# Does Amazon EC2 and RDS have ECC memory?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I know that Amazon's Cluster GPU Instances have ECC memory as mentioned on [their blog](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/new-ec2-instance-type-the-cluster-gpu-instance.html) but there's no mention of other instance types. There's a [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=203167) from back in 2007 that went unanswered. Does anyone know if they're running ECC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Disclaimer: Product Manager for EC2)

Just noticed this thread via Hacker News. In our experience, ECC memory is a requirement for server infrastructure, and all Amazon EC2 servers use ECC.  We will be updating our detail pages with that information soon.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, great to have official info on this. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Does Amazon EC2 use ECC memory?
>
> In our experience, ECC memory is necessary for server infrastructure,
> and all the hardware underlying Amazon EC2 uses ECC memory.

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/ as of 2020-11